# How to Copy Newest File through Network Folder to Another Folder path using Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I cannot copy the newest file from a network folder (e.g. \test01\test1\test) to another folder path (e.g. D:\Users\Desktop\test). I have been using the below script to run my Batch script:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "\\test01\test1\test" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
copy "%NewestFile%" "D:\Users\Desktop\test"
```

This script works fine if i only use folder path to copy.

Please help me...

Comment: Add the successfully executed code to the question, please.

Answer (score 2):

Next code snippet should copy the newest file:

```
pushd "\\test01\test1\test"
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR /B /O:D /A:-D') DO SET "NewestFile=%%I"
copy /b "%NewestFile%" "D:\Users\Desktop\test"
popd
```

- [pushd](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html): when a `UNC` path is specified, `PUSHD` will create a temporary drive map and will then use that new drive. The temporary drive letters are allocated in reverse alphabetical order, so if `Z:` is free it will be used first.
- `DIR /B /O:D`: with `/S` switch would sort output by folder (and subfolders) first and then lastly by date.
- `DIR /A:-D` excludes directories (folders) from output.
- `"delims="` instead of `"delims=|"`.
- `copy /b` forces binary copy.

Comment: Hi JosefZ, THANKS A LOT for your help with explanation! This script works well now. Appreciate it so much :-)